# Finding element in list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, matching

i'm very beginner of Scheme and try to figure out how it is functioning; so i want to write a basic code:
first of all i have a definition set:    *zipcode (ZIPCODE CITY STATE)*

```
(define zipcodes '(
 (96774 ookala hawaii)
 (90001 losangeles california)
 (90263 malibu california)
 (10044 newyork newyork)
 ))
```

i try to write a function that input is zipcode and return city and state name for example:

```
 >(find '10044)
 (list 'newyork 'newyork)

 >(find '99999)
 empty because there is not zipcode like that.
```

Thanks a lot...

I'm not allowed to us LET function

Comment: You won't need the single quote in front of the numbers.

Comment: Thanks alot is this because numbers cannot be variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define filter
   (lambda (proc lst)
       (cond ((null? lst) '())
             ((proc (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (filter proc (cdr lst))))
             (else
                (filter proc (cdr lst))))))

(define find-zip
   (lambda (zip lst)
      (define match (filter (lambda (item) (= zip (car item))) lst))
      (if (null? match)
          '()
          (cdar match))))

(define (find zip)
    (find-zip zip zipcode))
```

I think that will work for you.  Filter will apply its first argument (a procedure) to each item in its second argument, which needs to be a list.  The first argument needs to return a boolean value for each item it's passed.  Filter will then return a list with all of the items that returned true when the first argument was applied.  Otherwise, it returns an empty list.

In this case, each item in the list you're passing is itself a list of 3 items, so it compares the first item in that list with the zip code you're looking for.  If it's a match, it returns true.  So if the zip code is in the list, it will return the three item sub-list.  Then we check to see if we got an empty list, if so, then we return an empty list.  Otherwise, we take the cdr of the car to get your desired city and state.

Comment: filter isn't in r5rs or r6rs, and given that we don't know what the guy is using, this presents a problem

Comment: Added a quick implementation of filter.

Comment: by the way i used r5rs but i am not allowed to use let function :(

Comment: The issue you were having with let was due to me not closing the parens properly.  Try it now.

Comment: it is not working like i try to do.... it requires to enter two elements... for exp: (find-zip 90001) returns: procedure find-zip: expects 2 arguments, given 1: 90001... and i'm not allowed to use let function.

Comment: My procedure needed the second argument to be 'zipcode', your list of the zipcodes, cities, and states.  I added a 'find' procedure that does exactly what your question outlines.

Comment: so.. how can i reduce let function from this code? is that possible

Comment: I added a wrapper function.  *find* will now work as your question outlines.

Comment: let is just syntactic sugar.  It can be changed to a define.

Answer (score 6):

Use `assoc`

```
> (assoc 90001 zipcodes)
(90001 losangeles california)
> (cdr (assoc 90001 zipcodes))
(losangeles california)
```

Comment: when i change my language to R5RS, it run like a miracle :).. but it don not give empty if there is not zipcode like entered

Comment: and assoc code is only search in firs element of lists of zipcodes for example if i try to find zipcode with city name.. its not working.. for example (assoc losangeles zipcodes) do not return something meaningful

Comment: @MichaelAdam your question didn't mention anything about looking up by city.

Answer (score 1):

Well so you can basically just filter the list for the zip code, I have sketched some code below (I'd write it differently, except I don't know what you have available outside of what is defined in RnRS).

```
(define find-zip
  (lambda (zip codelist)
   (if (empty? codelist) empty
    (if (= zip (car (car codelist)) (list (cadr (car codelist)) (caddr (car codelist)))
        (find-zip zip (cdr codelist))))))
```

It would probably be better should you use a let, and I think most implementations have a filter function that let you do this better.

Comment: You need to add a base case.  Right now, your procedure will run forever if the zip isn't in codelist.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to check if list is empty, that said it would crash rather than run forever

Comment: actually your code is very helpful but i want to create a function find-zip with only one element, i think there is two.. how can i do this with one element ?

Comment: Just have a helper function, so something like

(define find-zip (lambda (zip) (find-zip zip zipcodes)))